# Fastest and easiest way in KALIYUGA to attain LIBERATION

Tags: belief, practice, moksha, kali-yuga

What are the fastest and easiest ways in KALIYUGA to get rid of LUST, ANGER, GREED,FALSE PRIDE and ENVY of ONE's SELF?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best and easy methods to earn lots of punya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46147/best-and-easy-methods-to-earn-lots-of-punya)

Comment: Focus on these words. If you really get the import of what I have listed, you may not be liberated but you will definitely be **awakened**. > When **you** move and jump around in **you**r dreams even as **you** lie on the
> bed, *which is the real **you***? >
>
>
>
>
> ---
>
>
>
>
>
>
>What happens to **you** in deep dreamless
> sleep? What is **you**r experience of "**you**"? Hint: You experience the world through the five senses, which report to the mind, which reports to you... We see the world inside-out whereas the real thing is outside-in.

Comment: Gaining Punya is not in the same league as awakening or Self Realization or Liberation. Punya is simply extended loitering in samsaara.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HSE. Kindly visit [How Does a New User Get Started on HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). Have an enriching journey ahead.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me with your various explanations, understanding and experiences.  But i found from KALISANTARANA UPANISAD,very interesting one.                    http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/kali-santarana-upanisad.pdf

Comment: There is no "fast and easy way". All ways require effort. Otherwise everyone would have achieved liberation now.

Answer (score 6):

##### The easiest (and the only) path to Mokṣha in the age of Kaliyuga is the *japa, bhajan, dhyāna, saṅkīrtana* of Hari aka Lord Viṣhṇu.

<sup>(This answer is mainly from a Vaiṣhṇava literature-based perspective)</sup>

---

Lord Viṣhṇu says in Padma Purana: [Uttara Khanda - 92.21/22](https://www.transliteral.org/pages/z201120195938/view) :

> नाहं वसामि वैकुंठे योगिनां हृदये न च ॥२१॥
> मद्भक्ता यत्र गायंति तत्र तिष्ठामि नारद
>
> nāhaṃ vasāmi vaikuṃṭhe yogināṃ hṛdaye na ca ॥21॥
> madbhaktā yatra gāyaṃti tatra tiṣṭhāmi nārada
>
> > Meaning:
> >
> > “I do not live in Vaikuṇṭha, nor in the heart of the yogins.
> >  O Nārada, I stay there where my devotees sing my praise.

So, Lord Viṣhṇu resides wherever his glory is sung by his devotees.

Further, the real significance of Hari-bhajan is expounded in the [Bṛihana-Nāradīya-  Purāṇa](https://ia800704.us.archive.org/30/items/BrihanNaradiyaPurana/brhan_naradiya_purana.pdf) which states:

> हरेर्नाम हरेर्नाम हर्र्नामैव केवलम्।
>  कलौ नास्त्येव नास्त्येव नास्त्येव
> गतिरन्यथा ॥ ३८.१२६॥
>
> harernāma harernāma harrnāmaiva kevalam।
>  kalau nāstyeva nāstyeva
> nāstyeva gatiranyathā ॥38.126॥
>
> > **The nama of Hari, the nama of Hari, the nama of Hari alone [is the only
> > way].
> >  In the age of Kali there is no other path to Liberation.** ॥38.126॥

Vyasa says the following in [Book 6: Chapter 2](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp157.htm) of Vishnu Purana

> कृते यजन् यज्ञैस्त्रेतायां द्वापरेऽर्चयन्।
>  यदाप्नोति तदाप्नोति कलौ सङ्कीर्त्य केशवम् [।। १७ ।।](https://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/visnu-purana/chapter-120/topic-1)
> kṛte yajan yajñaistretāyāṃ dvāpare'rcayan ।
> yadāpnoti tadāpnoti kalau saṅkīrtya keśavam ॥17॥
>
> > **"That reward which a man obtains in the Krita by abstract meditation, in the Treta by sacrifice, in the Dwápara by adoration, he receives in the Kali by merely reciting the name of Keśava." ॥17॥**

Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) at [12.3.51](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/3/51/) also concurs with the greatness of Hari-naam *japa* to destory material bondages.

**Hence, regular chanting of *Hari-naam* is a way to liberation.**

---

In the [Viṣhṇu Sahasranāmam](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/vsahasranew.html) (from the [Mahābhārata](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Vishnu_Sahasranamam)) we are told the same:

> यस्य स्मरणमात्रेण जन्मसंसारबन्धनात् ।
>  विमुच्यते नमस्तस्मै विष्णवे
> प्रभविष्णवे ॥६॥
>
> > **Even a mere thought of Whom makes one liberated from the bondage of
> > Samsara (birth and death) –
> >  To that all-powerful Lord (Viṣhṇu), my
> > profound salutations.**

Further, in the same Sahasranāmam Yudhiṣṭhira questions Pitāmaha Bhīṣhma the same as follows:

> युधिष्ठिर उवाच:
> किमेकं दैवतं लोके किंवाप्येकं परायणम् ।
> स्तुवन्तः कं कमर्चन्तः प्राप्नुयुर्मानवाः शुभम् ।।२।।
>
> > Yudhiṣṭhira asks:
> > (O Grandfather!) Who is the One Supreme Lord in this Universe? Who is
> > One refuge for all?
> > Who should be praised? And by worshipping Whom can a person reach
> > auspiciousness (peace and prosperity)?
>
> को धर्मः सर्वधर्माणां भवतः परमो मतः ।
> किं जपन्मुच्यते जन्तुर्जन्मसंसारबन्धनात् ।।३।।
>
> > What is, in Your opinion, the greatest Dharma of all Dharmas?
> > And **by chanting Whose mantra, can a creature proceed beyond the bonds of
> > Samsara?**

And Pitāmaha Bhīṣhma replies as:

> भीष्म उवाच:
> जगत्प्रभुं देवदेवमनन्तं पुरुषोत्तमम् ।
>  स्तुवन्नामसहस्रेण पुरुषः
> सततोत्थितः ।।४।।<br
>
> > Bhisma replied:
> >  He Who is the Lord of the Universe,
> > Who is the God of Gods, Who is limitless,
> >  and Who is the Supreme
> > Purusha (Spirit); One who praises that Lord by the Sahasranama (the
> > thousand names);
>
> तमेव चार्चयन्-नित्यं भक्त्या पुरुषमव्ययम् ।
>  ध्यायन् स्तुवन्-नमस्यंश्च
> यजमानस्तमेव च ।।५।।
>
> > One who worships and prays, daily without break, that Purusha Who does
> > not change (Who is imperishable) -
> >  By meditating on Him, praising Him
> > and making prostrations on Him;
>
> अनादि-निधनं विष्णुं सर्वलोक-महेश्वरम् ।
>  लोकाध्यक्षं स्तुवन्-नित्यं
> सर्वदुःखातिगो भवेत् ।।६।।
>
> > To that Lord Who is beyond the six changes beginning with origin
> > (birth) and ending with death, Who is the greatest Lord of all the
> > worlds,
> >  And Who is the knower of the world; **one who worships that Lord
> > by singing His name, such a devotee transcends over all the sorrows (duhka) of
> > this material world (attains liberation)** -
>
> ब्रह्मण्यं सर्वधर्मज्ञं लोकानां कीर्ति-वर्धनम् ।
>  लोकनाथं महद्भूतं
> सर्वभूत-भवोद्-भवम् ।।७।।
>
> > By worshipping Him Who is the protector of the Brahma and the Vedas,
> > Who is the knower of Dharma, Who increases the fame of all people,
> >  Who
> > is the Master of the Universe, Who is exceedingly wonderful, and from
> > Whom the world along with all other beings have originated.
>
> एष मे सर्वधर्माणां धर्मोऽधिकतमो मतः ।
>  यद्भक्त्या पुण्डरीकाक्षं
> स्तवैरर्चेन्नरः सदा ।।८।।
>
> > **I consider this to be the most superior to all other forms of Dharma -**
> > The Dharma which consists of unfailing adoration to that lotus-eyed
> > Lord with the hymns of praise recited with devotion.
>
> यतः सर्वाणि भूतानि भवन्त्यादियुगागमे ।
>  यस्मिंश्च प्रलयं यान्ति पुनरेव
> युगक्षये ।।११।।
>
> > He from Whom all beings have come into existence at the beginning of
> > the cycle of time (creation),
> >  And He into Whom all beings dissolve at
> > the end of the cycle (dissolution);
>
> तस्य लोकप्रधानस्य जगन्नाथस्य भूपते।
>  विष्णोर्नामसहस्रं मे शृणु
> पापभयापहम् ।।१२।।
>
> > He Who is the chief of the world, He Who is the Lord and King of the
> > world,
> >  **And He Who is the remover of all sins and fear – hear from me,
> > O King, the praise of that Lord which consists of the hymn of the
> > thousand names, also known as “Vishnu Sahasranama”.**

**Thus, for one of the best methods to remove all kinds of ills/hardships from one's life and to end the endless samsara cycle (i.e., attain Liberation), both Veda Vyāsa & Pitāmaha Bhīṣhma concurs with the recital of the Viṣhṇu Sahasranāmam as the best path.**

Furthermore, in the concluding part of the Sahasranāmam, Śhri Kṛiṣhṇa assures, that even a single name uttered with devotion is accepted by him:

> श्रीभगवानुवाच:
> यो मां नामसहस्रेण स्तोतुमिच्छति पाण्डव ।
>  सोहऽमेकेन श्लोकेन स्तुत एव न
> संशयः ॥२४॥
>
> > Lord Kṛiṣhṇa says: 
> > **He who likes to sing my praise, O Arjuna, using
> > these thousand names, Know you that I would be satisfied by his
> > singing of even a single stanza.** There is no doubt on this.

---

---

### tl;dr

##### So, to conclude, from the *Vaishnavas* perspective, The easiest & fastest (and the only) way to ameliorate all the material ills-hardships, and attain Liberation, in the age of Kaliyuga is the *japa* and *bhajan* of any of the names of Hari aka Lord Vishnu.

Comment: If someone mischants vishnu shashranaam due to lack of knowledge in sanskrit. So does all his sadhana fail? Whenever I read it I mischant a lot. Help please

Answer (score 4):

For Moksha in any and (especially in kali) yuga.:

MBH 13.14.:

> ***When the unrighteous or sinful Kali Yuga comes, one should never pass a moment without devoting his heart upon Mahadeva. One that has drunk the Amrita constituted by the devotion to Hara, one becomes freed from the fear of the world (by getting moksha).***

Mahabhagvata (Shakti Pithanka) Purana, 81.11-14.:

> ***It is the ultimate truth that In Kaliyuga, there is no other solution except worshiping Shiva** because through this one gets freedom from the bondage of evil with little bit of spiritual practices. That is because, by worshiping Lord Shiva, a person easily achieves success in Kaliyuga.  **In Kaliyuga, there is no action equal to the worship of Shambhu.  Whether one is a Shakta, Vaishnava or Shaiva, he should first worship Lord Shankara.  After this, one should worship one's Ishta Deva with devotion.***

Skanda-Māhapurāṇa,  Suta Samhita,  Muktikhanda, 3.40-47.:

> *Lord Shiv said- The devotees who worships other gods, attains Salokya etc. due to the difference in the superiority of the idol to be worshipped and the difference in the way he worships himself. Then, on becoming eligible for Krama moksha, **he comes to me through Brahmaloka and Vishnuloka and attains Kaivalya after getting the Vedanta knowledge about God from me.** The one who is not eligible for Krama moksha enjoys many pleasures in the world he worships and then gets a human body again. **The person who thinks that 'I am Shiva present in all the idols and worships me in this way, he also attains my supreme form in the above mentioned order according to the superiority of the particular idol to be worshipped and the difference in the one who worships, and attains Kaivalya by taking knowledge from me situated in Uttam Apa. But the one who believes in me in all the idols, attains me sooner than the one who does not think so. O Vishnu!  In the same way, by external actions also, by attaining me in a systematic manner and by taking the knowledge of Shiva from me, the soul becomes free, if the external action is performed with a pure heart.***

Shiva Purana 2.2.43.:

> ***Lord Śiva said:—***
>
> .
>
> *17. The base man who differentiates the deities of the Trinity certainly stays in hell as long as the moon and the stars shine.*
>
> *18. My devotee may worship the gods. Being so absorbed he will attain knowledge leading to eternal salvation.*
>
> *19. **Without devotion to Brahmā one cannot have the devotion to Viṣṇu; without devotion to Viṣṇu none will have devotion towards me.***

Skanda-Māhapurāṇa,  Suta Samhita,  Muktikhanda, 3.27-31.:

> ***Lord Shiva said- Hey Janardana! The person who worships you daily with devotion, this person with pure mind attains you and (after receiving teachings from you) in due course of time, finally attains me.** In the best worlds, even after enjoying the sensual pleasures, the living being becomes liberated by attaining knowledge. Or if the mind is not very pure, then after attaining Sarupya, Samipya or Salokya, it can gradually move towards salvation (or can come back to the mortal world). Hey Vishnu! One who worships your other forms, gets liberated gradually after getting this closeness. O Achyuta- One who worships your symbol or idols, after attaining this Salokya, gradually attains salvation as per his feelings **and finally after having vision of mine he attains Kaivalya through Tatvajnana.***

Śri Shiva Gita, 13.32.:

> *Bhagawan Shiva said to Shri Ramchandra.: Just as Kailash, Vaikuntha, Satya-Loka, Swarga, etc. are divine worlds, similarly **Moksha is not a world, Moksha is not a state of residing in any particular place. Nor does one have to go to any other world or places to attain it. Only the destruction of the knots of ignorance in the heart i.e. the end of the darkness of ignorance is salvation.***

For more you can read [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/48801/20968) answer of mine. Which is universal for all Shrutis ans Smritis period.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..